# Do Apache Gracefully finishing connections count as live(MaxClients limit)?

Tags: apache-2.2, process, connection, httpd.conf

For instance, I've got MaxClients = 128, and 28 connections are "Gracefully finishing". Does this mean that Apache can handle 100 connections at the moment, or "Gracefully finishing" do not count here and Apache can handle all 128?

Comment: What you mean "Gracefully finishing"? This connections in CLOSED state or in TIME_WAIT?